# How to access rewritten url from Salesforce Site

Tags: url-rewriting, salesforce, force.com, sites

I am using the Salesforce Sites URL rewriting feature, and need to retrieve the 'friendly' URL from the browser bar for some other processing.  Is there any way I can retrieve this from within either one of the sites pages (so I can pass into a component as an attribute) or from a component controller directly?

To explain further, I am seeing a url in browser presently of 'site.force.com/examplesite/amazingpage' but if I try to retrieve $CurrentPage.url to pass into a component, or use Url.getCurrentRequestUrl() from within a component controller the result is a typical salesforce url ie. 'site.force.com/vfpage?id=123456789'.

Any suggestions most appreciated.

Cheers,
CH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted.

Was obvious in the end - just added an additional method to the url rewriter class that allowed me to pass in a single url for rewriting, rather than trying to retrieve the re-written url from the view.

Cheers,
CH